# Equivalent of ASP.NET Partial View in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

My task is to create a Qt 5.5 window. The window's layout will be changed during runtime, dynamically. I would like to create some sort of a Partial View like in ASP.NET. For example, I have a list of people, and when I doubleclick a person in this list, the list disappear, and the person details are shown instead with a "Go back" button. I would like to create two 'PartialViews', one for the list, and one for the person details.

How do I do that? Do I have to create custom widgets, and add them dynamically to the window?

As the window will be very complex, I would not like to store everything in the MainWindow class.

PS: I would also like to use the Model/View pattern, so each "Partial view" would have its own Model.

Comment: UML or Widgets? And you always can implement this logic with visible :)

Comment: I an new to Qt, and I use the Qt Creator, so Widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt has his own [model view programming pattern](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html), so you can simply create a widget that do what you want implementing this pattern.

Comment: Ok, I see :) But how do I add this widget to the mainwindow? Do I have to create a DockWidget and call the MainWindow::addDockWidget method?

Comment: `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget` allows you to set the widget that main windows must shown as central one. You can create your own widget and then use it. You can also create your widget inheriting QDockWidget. You can show a dialog with your widget when needed. It depends on your application design. Once you create your widget you can use it in many ways.

Comment: @Darxis Are you sure you even need a `QMainWindow`? Note that this class is misnamed, you can have any widget type as the top-level widget, even simple things like `QLabel`.

Comment: I am going to use a main window, where I will create the layout and fill it with my custom widgets.